# Function works as expected in Code Playground not on production server.

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Any ideas why this loads and runs on the Code Playground and not on my production web server?? It should all function the same correct? I am new to js. I just need a few pointers maybe??

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function drawVisualization() {
         // Create and populate the data table.
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('string', 'x');
         data.addColumn('number', '% Und Sizer');
         data.addColumn('number', '% Und QC');
         data.addRow(["1-11", 1, 1]);
         data.addRow(["2-9.5", 2, 1]);
         data.addRow(["3-10", 4, 1]);
         data.addRow(["4-11", 8, 10]);
         data.addRow(["5-10.5", 7, 1]);
         data.addRow(["ELM-11.5", 7, 1]);
         data.addRow(["UND-11.5", 8, 1]);
         // Create and draw the visualization.
         new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, { curveType: "function", width: 900, height: 400,
      vAxes: { 0: { logScale: false, maxValue: 30 },
          1: { logScale: false, maxValue: 50 }
      },
      series: {
          0: { targetAxisIndex: 0 },
          1: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
      }
  }
      );
     }
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was calling the wrong element.